# How to use SecurityConfig in SpringSecurity properly

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am currently using the oauth2 client for my Webclient as follows:

```
@Bean("OAuth2Webclient")
WebClient webClient() {

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository = new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository();
    var oauth = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(getClientRegistrationRepository(), oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("myclientID");
    oauth.setClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient2());

    return WebClient.builder()
        .apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration()) // <- I would like to create the oauth object in the config file and inject it here as ooposed to creating it above
        .build();
}
```

The authorization server responds with non-standard field names, instead of the expected "access_token" attribute, I'm getting "accessToken", for "refresh_token" I get "refreshToken", etc; so I needed to create a custom token response converter which is given here to my object:

```
oauth.setClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient2());
```

There's some extra code to get the clientRegistrationRepository as well as the custom accessTokenResponseClient which I'm not including.

This works well but I am sure there's a more elegant way to do this using a SecurityConfig class. I played around with it but it is not clear to me how to use it. I tried a couple of options and it does create a bean at startup and I noticed that it does call the ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction constructor when the service starts up but how do I access this bean so I can add it to my webclient?

Basically, I'd like to include the above in a config class as below:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        ..{what to do here to replace my code above?}
    return http.build();
    }
}
```

Thanks for all your help.